# Is there a way to know if an unicode character is available in installed fonts?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, fonts, windows-10

I'm using the Blocks.txt from unicode.org which defines unicode character ranges.

I made some tool to display those character, per range, in a browser.

I downloaded the Noto font package.

Obviously I don't need to install all of those fonts, so is there a "programmingly" way to know if the browser/system is rendering a character, so I can only install the fonts I need? Or maybe to query if the system has an installed fonts for this character?

Maybe an easier way would be to learn what range of codepoints each single TTF from noto is supposed to render...

I just want to browse character as a hobby project.

Comment: There's nothing built into Python for this. You can call Windows APIs via pywin32, or .NET APIs by using IronPython or Python.NET, or any of a number of third-party libraries for parsing TrueType/OpenType files that you can search for on PyPI.

Comment: See [TTX/FontTools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/FontTools) for an example.

Comment: As you can read for Unicode standard, there is no direct relation between unicode codepoint, and font glyph. Having a glyph for a code, do no mean it is correct (it could be a fallback with a square and 4/5 unicode hexdigits). Or it could display it as single glyph, but the intention was to merge it to other codes. Same code, different language: should be displayed differently (either the single character, or how to "merge" characters). So: you should check what language a font support (and in what details), not the codepoint. Which is also a difficult task.